# Implement swipe to delete for UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to implement swipe to delete for UWP.

I have checked the documentation about implementing ContextActions, but this gives a context menu and not the swipe to delete behavior I am looking for.

Since [UWP supports this natively](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/swipe), anyway to override the implementation of XF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in Xamarin.Forms control that utilizes UWP' `SwipeControl` control, but you can implement it yourself by creating either a custom renderer of an existing control (see [documentation here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)) or a entirely custom view that is rendered as `SwipeControl` on UWP (see [documentation here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/)).

Comment: Oh, nice to meet you again :-) ! Happy coding!

Comment: Yearly unclosed answer review - @Mhd. Tahawi, if this heped, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is closed.